Can reminnia use the gnome pipewire for remote desktop support
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 and use Remmina against x11vnc for remote desktop. I just noticed that Gnome has support for sound for remote desktop with pipewire.
Could I make use of this with Remmina/x11vnc? If not what combination do I need?
